# pypy3 reading big file very slow

Tags: python-3.x, jit, pypy

I'm trying to use pypy3 to improve the efficiency of my code.
The basic flow is reading a very big file and do some processing and output.

pypy3 do improve the speed of the processing part, but very very slow in reading big file, much more slower than normal python3.....I suppose pypy3 doesn't compile it correctly, maybe I need to add some args to improve the reading file efficiency?

I read the file with built-in open function

```
with open(inF1, 'r') as f:
    gtf = [line.split('\t') for line in f]
```